# Why doesn't this regex work for c++ TR1?

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

I admit it's been a while since I've worked with C++, but from what I can tell, my code should work.  I'm trying to replace/remove all block comments from a file containing code.  I put the whole file I'm searching into a string, and the string contains newline characters.

Here's my code

```
std::tr1::regex rx1("[/][*][\S\s]*?[*][/]");
stringName = std::regex_replace(stringName, rx1, std::string(""));
```

As far as I can tell, this should match /*anything in here including new lines */

I've even tested it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, where it matches block comments perfectly.  Problem is, block comments aren't being replaced.  Is this some kind of TR1 specific bug?

Comment: you should escape back-slashes "\\"

Comment: `*?` is that legal? Match as often as you want but at least once? Isn't it equivalent to `+`?

Comment: @RedX: The `?` is a non-greedy modifier to the `*`.

Comment: I've actually run into less problems when putting literals inside of [] instead of escaping them. Is there a specific reason I should escape them rather than put each literal in a []?

Comment: *? is legal. It matches as few characters as possible before moving onto the next match.  The important part there is that the next match takes precedence over the preceding match

Comment: As far as escaping the backslashes, I tried this code, but it gives the exact same result(nothing gets replaced).  std::tr1::regex rx3("\/[*][\S\s]*?[*]\/");

Comment: @Brandon: That's not what Jared meant. He said to escape your backslashes, not to escape your literals with backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightness Races in Orbit pushed me along the right path, but turns out the * and ? cannot be used on arguments within [] brackets.  The way to do that is use a noncapturing group which has or statements.

Code to find multi-line block comments:

```
std::tr1::regex rx3("[/][*](?:\s|.|\n)*?[*][/]");
```

(?:expression) is how to make a noncapturing group.  You can apply the * and ? to the outside of that.  Inside of it, use | as an or statement.

Comment: `*?` absolutely _can_ apply to character classes, unless `tr1`'s implementation is _completely_ stupid.

Answer (score 3):

You have to consider that there are layers to what you're doing.

- First, you're building a string inside a string literal. To a human it looks like a regular expression, but the string literal doesn't care.

  That string literal contains, among other things, the special characters that are yielded by `\S` and `\s` respectively (just like how `\n` is special).
- Then, you're passing this string — special characters and all — to the regex engine.

Instead, you do need to perform escaping of the backslashes, *just for the string literal*:

```
std::tr1::regex rx1("[/][*][\\S\\s]*?[*][/]")
```

The regex engine will then see the expression properly:

```
[/][*][\S\s]*?[*][/]
```

---

Also, I'd check whether tr1's engine requires delimiters. They're usually a good idea.

Comment: Or one can use a raw string literal: `R"([/][*][\S\s]*?[*][/])"` No escape sequences are interpreted inside a raw string literal. Even trigraphs, digraphs, and UCN interpretation, which happens in an earlier phase, is _undone_ inside a raw string literal. Raw string literals seem to be intended for two things, regexs or similar strings, and multi-line string literals.

Comment: @Bames53: Yep, or that. How are trigraphs "undone", though? The preprocessor passes enough information to the compiler for that?

Comment: I see what you mean about having to delimit the backslash. I should have caught that. That said, for whatever reason, it still isn't working.  Is it possible to use the * function on things in []?  I'm beginning to think not, and I didn't see any examples one way or the other on the msdn site.  If not, you can tell what I'm trying to do. How else would I go about this?

Comment: @BrandonSee: No reason why not. Did you check about delimiters?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit From what I can tell, no. However, I believe I was right in thining I couldn't apply the * or ? to something in []. I had to use a noncapturing group which had or statements.  std::tr1::regex rx3("[/][*](?:\s|.|\n)*?[*][/]");

Comment: @BrandonSee: That's been valid since `perlre`. That's _decades_ old. I have a hard time believing that your implementation's `std::tr1::regex` can't do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I looks to me like the standard describes reverting trigraph transformations as occurring in the preprocessor as well. "If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character: — If the next character begins a sequence of characters that could be the prefix and initial double quote of a raw string literal [...] the next preprocessing token shall be a raw string literal. [...] any transformations performed in phases 1 and 2 (trigraphs, universal-character-names, and line splicing) are reverted;" [§ 2.5 p3]

Comment: @bames53: Ah ok, that makes sense. I'd treat the preprocessor as a black box and just say "then the transformations will never be seen to have occurred in the first place" :D